# Capture multiline content between two words in javascript with RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to parse something like this in regexp (js)

```
CODE
some stuff which contains
even linebreaks
END

CODE
anothEr block of code
END
```

I want to get all between CODE and END
That works with:

```
/CODE([^(?!END)]*)END/g
```

The problem is when there is E, N or D somewhere between CODE and END, that's because the second block won't be matched.

So the negative lookahead checks for E, or N or D and not the word "END". 
Is there a way for negative lookahead for the whole Word "END" ?

martin

Comment: ^ [Basically](http://regex101.com/r/eG6tB5) `/CODE((?:(?!END)[\s\S])*)END/g`

Comment: Thank, you! Suddenly everything seems clear... oh regex

Comment: You could use a non greedy star: `*?`.
http://regex101.com/r/zL1vN3